# Overwrite repositories - --force push

Tags: git

I have really big problem, I used command:

```
git push --force origin master
git reflog
f8037dd HEAD@{11}: commit (initial): doc
```

Now I have 1 commit, how I can restore last 25 commits? Veeeryy thanks for help :))

Comment: Please add more info about where the lost commits were — on the current local branch, on another branch locally, on the master branch on remote, etc?  If they were on master remotely and not your machine, it may be difficult or impossible to recover.  If someone can push the commits up again from another clone of the code, that would be ideal.  You can avoid force pushing next time by doing development on a feature branch then merging.

Comment: We use Gerrit to host the projects. The updates of refs are recorded by reflogs in the server-side repos. You could ask the server administrator for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why only one commit in your local repo, and why needs force override the remote repo.

`git push --force` will overriding your remote repo, is a **danger** command, must be careful.

Is another branches exist or another contributors have a copy of repo?

Comment: Files is not a problem. I have it but don't have history on page github. I have one more local repo.

Comment: @Graku BTW GitHub preserve reflog of repository, so it is easy to recover the commit master point to before last push.

Comment: I used other repo in GUI git and this GUI seen all after commits :D Soo lucky

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: never, never ever use the `push --force`, unless you consciously want to destroy the repository or its part.

How to recover from that? If you didn't messed your local copy after the `push -f`, run:

```
git fsck --unreachable --dangling | sed -n -e '/^unreachable commit / { s/unreachable commit \(.*\)/tag_\1 \1/; p} ' | xargs -L1 git tag
```

Look for new tags - gitk or gitg may be helpful - and recover from that. Good luck.

---

BTW, I've just noticed you've stated under other answer you have other local repo. If you have the history in that repo, why you won't push the commits?

Comment: I used other save repo on my pc in GUI GIT, and this program see all after commits ;))